# What uniting term are subjects, objects, verbs, etc called?

Tags: terminology

A noun, verb, adjective, adverb, pronoun, preposition, conjunction, interjection or article is a part of speech or a word class.
A subject, object, verb, complement, adverbial, modifier or supplement is a what? What term are they called?

Comment: They are called **functions**. In all clauses, every constituent at word level is assigned 2 labels: a category label (part of speech) and a function label.

Answer (score 1):

They are called functions (or grammatical relations. –
nschneid). In all clauses, every constituent at word level is assigned 2 labels: a category label (part of speech) and a function label. –
BillJ

Comment: Grammatical functions or grammatical relations.

Answer (score 0):

from [wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_relation):

> In linguistics, **grammatical relations** (also called **grammatical functions**, **grammatical roles**, or **syntactic functions**) are functional relationships between constituents in a clause.

[image: CGELFunctions]